# Where is my xfce in ubuntu11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, xfce

I recently(now) installed xfce in ubuntu 11.10. I used:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

It downloads 22mb approx. files. Then i restarted my pc, it asked my password. I **didn't** type my password. I closed this window (I thought it may be a virus/hack).

After restart, there is no xfce. Again I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

But no use. It says xfce4 with latest. installed already.

What do I need to do now?

Comment: did you select the option to encrypt your home folder?  If you did, I expect this is the password it was prompting you for to unlock your encrypted folder...

Comment: Or possibly it was gdm (or whatever) offering you the option to pick a desktop before logging in?

Comment: xubuntu-desktop is the 'proper' package to use

Answer (score 4):

- Log out
- Click on menu in display manager (a small star near username at login screen)
- Select XFCE
- Login
- Enjoy